# Unable to load data in page load using MobX and React js

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I am new MobX with react.js and I am very excited to explore more about react. I googled a lot and tried the sample with the help of the below link, but no luck.

[Enabling decorators - MobX](https://mobx.js.org/enabling-decorators.html)

Can someone please step in and help me with this? I am doing this as a POC to start my project. It is a blocker and it means a lot for me at this time

**model.ts**

```
export interface IActivity {
    id: string;
    title: string;
    description: string;
    category: string;
    date: string;
    city: string;
    venue: string;
}
```

**agent.ts**

```
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from 'axios';

axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://localhost:xxx/api';

const responseBody = (response: AxiosResponse) => response.data;
const requests = { get: (url: string) => axios.get(url).then(responseBody) };
const Activities = { list: () => requests.get('/activities/getactivities') };

// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-anonymous-default-export
export default { Activities };
```

**activityStore.ts**

```
import { observable, action, makeObservable } from 'mobx';
import { createContext } from 'react';
import { IActivity } from './../models/agent';
import agent from '../api/agent';

class ActivityStore {
    @observable activities: IActivity[] = [];

    constructor() {
        makeObservable(this);
    }

    @action loadActivities = () => {
        agent.Activities.list().then((response) => {
            this.activities.push(response);
        });
    };
}

export const activityStoreContext = createContext(new ActivityStore());
```

**App.tsx**

```
import { useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react-lite';
import { activityStoreContext } from '../src/stores/activityStore';

const App = observer(() => {
    const activityStore = useContext(activityStoreContext);

    const display = activityStore.activities.map((activity) => (
        <li key={activity.id}>{activity.title}</li>
    ));

    useEffect(() => {
        activityStore.loadActivities();
    }, [activityStore]);

    return (
        <div>
            <ul>{display}</ul>
        </div>
    );
});

export default App;
```

**package.json**

[image]

**Output from edge browser (same in chrome and firefox as well)**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Decorators alone are not enough in `mobx@6.0.0` or later versions. You need to use [`makeObservable(this)` in the constructor of `ActivityStore` as well](https://mobx.js.org/enabling-decorators.html).

If the response to `agent.Activities.list()` is an array, you likely want to push all the elements in this array to the `this.activities` array, not push the entire array.

```js
agent.Activities.list().then((response) => {
    this.activities.push(...response);
});
```